# Azure, App service, "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Having an App in Azure app services. A .NET web project.

Running the line:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\home\site\wwwroot\Prod-Enterprise-Test-6-26-2016-credentials.publishsettings")
```

will throw an exception

> The system cannot find the file specified.

you can see the file is there and believe me it is not miss spelling, locally it works fine and fail when deployed.

[image: The file is in the correct path as you can see]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was in a different location in the code.
The code as published works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The code you mentioned need to be changed as following:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\Prod-Enterprise-Test-6-26-2016-credentials.publishsettings")
```

You mentioned that will throw not found exception, it is very odd. The code should work in the azure website if the file is existing.

> The system cannot find the file specified.

It seems that expection is caused by other codes. We also could [remote debug the WebApp with Vistual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) and we could get the more detail info about exception.

We also could add a sample test aspx page to test it. The following is my test steps.

1.Create a .net Web project and the index.aspx page

2.Add the code to index.aspx.CS file and index.aspx file

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          var file= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\Prod-Enterprise-Test-6-26-2016-credentials.publishsettings");
            Label1.Text = file;
        }
```

index.aspx

```
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </div>
```

3.Publish the Website to azure environment and add the setting file with content "Test info" via the Kudu tool
 [image]

4. Visit the index page from the browser and check that it works correctly.

[image]

Comment: This does not help

Comment: Do you have a try to remote debug the WebApp?

Comment: I cannot remote debug, it is version 2.2 of the Azure sdk and there is some bug there. I can write to log though.

Comment: If it is possible please have a try with latest [Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).